# React components large size

Tags: reactjs

Is it normal to have over 700kB in file size for a react component?
This is the file size after compilation.

```
  GridComponent.js   732 kB       0  [emitted]  GridComponent
  main.js  7.97 kB       1  [emitted]  main
```

`GridComponent` is the react component. `main` is normal js for comparison.

Is that normal?
I plan to only include react components in pages that requires them.

Comment: Is it normal for a car to cost US$100k?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that you're using webpack in your app, and your `GridComponent.js` should have something like `require('react');` (or `import React from 'react';`, if using ES6 modules with babel).

When you require things, webpack will "join" all your dependencies in the specified "output" settings (provided in `webpack.config.js`). So, if you check the contents of `GridComponent.js` you'll see that React is inside. In your case, this `GridComponent.js` is your "bundled file" (it will contain all the dependencies that you've imported). That's why it seems to be "large", because this file contains your component and React itself (and other dependencies as well).

When you say "I plan to only include react components in pages that requires them.", I think you may want to *split* your code, so your page will only load the things you need. You can check more info about code splitting here:

https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html

A basic "splitting" strategy would be to split your "vendor" code from your "app" code (https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html#split-app-and-vendor-code). In your case, React, React DOM and other "common" dependencies would go to "vendor", and your app is the code you've written.

But just as tip, code splitting is only **really** needed when you have lots of code. Because sometimes an extra network request may introduce more "latency" than downloading a few more bytes. Or if you have some "special" caching strategy, since your app may change more times than your vendor code (your vendor code will only be downloaded again when some dependency version is changed), and you avoid downloading lots of bytes when a simple thing is changed in your app.

I think this solves your question, but to add more information here, if you want to distribute your code to more people (i.e. an open source project), you may distribute your code and say "ok, to run that, you must install that other dependency", and you can achieve that with [peer dependencies](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/).

If peer dependencies is not your case, you can save some bytes by minifying your file (you can do that by modifying your webpack configuration). A good  blog post talking about that can be found here:

http://moduscreate.com/optimizing-react-es6-webpack-production-build/

Comment: Right. So I shouldn't need to import react and react-dom in my components, but to include the min files in my HTML instead right?

Comment: No, that kind of behavior (adding all dependencies to same file) is kind correct, since your page will load everything that is necessary to run your application. I will update my answer with the "code splitting" option, that may be what you want to do.

Comment: @resting, just updated my answer with information about "code splitting". Is that what you want to do?

Comment: Thanks. That is useful. But I tried adding vendor code into the `<head>` itself and remove any instance of `import react, react-dom` and it works fine too. Components are now down to 6kB.